# onResourceRequested fails to fire

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am running my tests on **Karma** with **Jasmine** framework and a headless browser **PhantomJS**.

I can't get `onResourceRequested` to be "fired", after injecting javascript file in `onCallback`. I tested `onCallback` execution, and it is fired plus the `page.injectJs` returns `true`, aka succeed.

here is my configuration file for **Karma** (look for comments with '#'):

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    'use strict';

    config.set({
        autoWatch: false,
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: [
            'jasmine'
        ],
        files: [
            // my test files
        ],
        exclude: [
        ],
        port: 8080,
        browsers: [
            'PhantomJS'
        ],
        plugins: [
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
        ],
        reporters: ['progress'],
        phantomjsLauncher: {
            options: {
                lastRequest: null,
                onCallback: function(data) {

                    var externalAPI = {
                        getLastRequest: function() {
                            return page.lastRequest;
                        },
                        clearLastRequest: function() {
                            page.lastRequest = null;
                        }
                    };

                    if (data.hasOwnProperty('require')) {
                        return page.injectJs(data.require);  // #SUCCEED!!!#
                    } else if (externalAPI.hasOwnProperty(data)) {
                        return externalAPI[data]();
                    }

                    return false;
                },
                onResourceRequested: function(request) {
                    page.lastRequest = request; // #DIDN'T HAPPEN AFTER injectJs succeed......#
                }
            },
            exitOnResourceError: true
        },
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 10000,
        singleRun: true,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    });
};
```

How can I make `onResourceRequested` to happen after `page.injectJs`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[`page.injectJs(filename)`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html) synchronously reads the local file and injects it synchronously into the page. There is no network request, so there is no need to trigger the `onResourceRequested` event listener.

Comment: So, how can I "listen" to resources loaded into the page?

Comment: Why do you have to "listen" to them if you're loading them yourself? Do your stuff before or after `page.injectJs(data.require)`.